# Is there a better way to link to a configuration specific static lib on iOS than OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

Situation:  Linking against an SDK (which I'm building) that has Release, Debug, & Distribution versions of it's static library (.a file).  There doesn't seem to be a way in Xcode GUI to indicate that a static library is only used for a given Configuration.

I can use "Other Linker Flags" (OTHER_LDFLAGS) in the Build pane of the target or project settings like this:

`-all_load -ObjC "${SRCROOT}/MySDKFolder/${CONFIGURATION}-universal/libMYsdk.a"`

which *seems* to work.  Just wondering if anyone knows a better way.  ( the `-all_load` and `-ObjC` are to get ObjC categories linked in properly).

I'm using gcc 4.2 at this point (SDK default for 4.3 sdk and 3.x.x Xcode).

Comment: One can add the directories to the search path with the same ${CONFIGURATION} type string, but when you add the actual .a file to the project it adds a link to a particular file so you only get that version of the .a file/library.

Comment: There's now way to edit the path of a file that's been added to the project such that you can put the ${CONFIGURATION) type things into it.  You may only choose files via the file system.  At least that I've found.

Comment: Actually, you can manually edit the path in the project.pbxproj file. The file will appear in red in Xcode but it will be properly resolved at link time. Bu that's equivalent to what you did in the OTHER_LDFLAGS setting.

Comment: thanks, but YIKES! :-) Not sure that qualifies as "better".  You're such the hacker 0xced :-D    (said with the utmost respect)

Comment: actually, one way this _might_ be better is if this makes the project notice that these files have changed and thus does the dependency checking properly.  Given that it's showing them in red as if it's not finding them, I'm thinking not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out I was letting the Xcode UI confuse me.  If you add the generic search path with the ${CONFIGURATION} variables and then add one of the static library instances to the project and target it'll do the right thing and link with the right one even though if you get info on that library in the project it'll show you the specific path.

However, if you want it to actually have Xcode notice changes made to one of the static libraries, you'll need to add ALL versions of your static library to the project and target (yes, it'll look like it's linking with all three, no worries!).

To have Xcode detect the the .a file changed as the result of a build script phase you have to actually have all the source files that are used to build the .a file in the Run Script Input pane (a pain!) to not have to run your build script every time; And all three variants of the .a file in the output pane so Xcode knows what to check after your script runs to see if it needs to relink the project.